# operator overloading with templates in c++

Tags: c++, class, overloading

I need to overload basic operators to work with primitive types:

`Frac` - Common fraction class; `Frac(a,b) = a/b`. This is overload of `operator >`

```
template<typename t>
bool Frac::operator > (const t &right) {
if((long double)right)
    return ((long double)right < this->toLongDouble());
else
    cout << "Error!";
}
```

in main:

```
cout << ((Frac(1,2) > 2.5));
```

I have error:

```
 Error: undefined reference to `bool Frac::operator><double>(double const&)'
```

Comment: Where `bool Frac::operator >` is defined ? in a cpp (if so read [why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file))?

Comment: Error suggests that the template was not instantiated. It this template definition in header or in cpp?

Comment: BTW: should be const : `bool Frac::operator > (const t &right) const`. And I don't think that `if ((long double)right)` do what you want...